# buscar los primeros valores en un ciclo

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Necesito crear un ciclo que agarre los primeros 5 elementos de una lista que contiene la letra c ej "c4", "c7" etc... y luego, agarre los primeros 4 elementos que contiene otra lista con la letra a, los una en una lista y luego lo muestre en una tupla.

se hacer el buscar en la lista, sin embargo no sé como crear el ciclo para que agarre los primeros 5 y 4 elementos y los añada a otra lista en manera conjunta.

```
shuffle(balotas)  #mezcla las balotas

balotera = [ s for s in balotas if "N" in s]  #Busca a letra determinada en la lista mezclada

balotas_minimas=(print(tuple(balotera)))    ##convierte la lista a tupla y la muestra
```

Comment: puedes utilizar slice ejemplo   balotera[0:5] ejemplo español https://cupi2-ip.github.io/IPBook/nivel3/seccion3-4.html

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Podrías hacerlo con [`slices`](https://cupi2-ip.github.io/IPBook/nivel3/seccion3-4.html#:%7E:text=Slicing,-Objetivo%20de%20la&text=El%20objetivo%20de%20esta%20secci%C3%B3n,o%20una%20cadena%20de%20caracteres.) (Como lo comentó Bryro) o utilizando [`enumerate`](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/enumerar-en-python-ejemplo-de-enumeracion-de-python-para-indice-de-bucle/#:%7E:text=La%20funci%C3%B3n%20enumerate()%20dentro,olvidar%20incrementar%20manualmente%20a%20contador%20.) y solo obtener los primeros N índices.

Para juntar las dos listas puedes simplemente utilizar `+`, si "sumas" dos listas obtienes una lista con todos los valores de la primera lista y de la segunda lista.

Ejemplo:

```
import random

lista1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6' , 'a7', 'a8', 'a9', 'a10']
lista2 = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6' , 'c7', 'c8', 'c9', 'c10']

random.shuffle(lista1)
random.shuffle(lista2)

#Obtener los primeros 4 elementos con comprensión de listas y enumerate
resultado = [x for i, x in enumerate(lista1) if (('a' in x) and (i < 4))]

#Obtener los primeros 5 elementos con comprensión de listas y slice
#Nota, se utiliza el operador de asignación += para agregar los primeros 5 elementos que contengan "c" a la lista de resultado
resultado += [x for x in lista2 if 'c' in x][0:5]

#Imprimir la tupla
print(tuple(resultado))
```

Esto devuelve una tupla con 4 valores que contienen "a" y 5 valores que contienen "c"

```
('a10', 'a8', 'a4', 'a3', 'c3', 'c10', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7')
```